# Email templates customization - header, footer + css

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

When I place an order, I'm receiving an email with the next content:

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}} {{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

Thank you for your order from MYSITE.

Once your package ships we will send an email with a link to track your order. Your order summary is below. Thank you again for your business.

Your order #100000014
....
{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

I've created my `email-inline.css` in the folder **skin/frontend/mysite/default/css** but don't know what to do for showing the header/footer and apply that css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this upgrading my magento from version 1.9.0.1 to latest 1.9 one: 1.9.2.4.

After this change

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header"}} {{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
```

is replaced with the right content.